# como dar dois splits em um txt

Tags: python

Quero dar dois splits um para excluir linhas do txt e outro para excluir o separador dele no txt tem nome:sobrenome ex Rafael:Lima o separador e ":" como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Como estás a fazer até agora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei como estás a abrir o ficheiro, mas aqui fica o que julgo ser a melhor maneira:

```
with open('FICHEIRO.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        nome, apelido = line.split(':') # nome = Rafael, apelido.split() = Lima
```

Se quiseres guardar numa lista todos os nomes ex:

> Rafael:Lima
> Carla:Borges

podes:

```
nomes = []
with open('FICHEIRO.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        nome, apelido = line.split(':') # separar linha pelos dois pontos
        nomes.append((nome, apelido.strip())) # remover a quebra de linha no apelido

print(nomes) # [('Rafael', 'Lima'), ('Carla', 'Borges')]
```

Comment: Otimo amigo!, era isso mesmo que eu queria fazer muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @Adrianoguedes

Comment: Porem gostaria de remover também o \n que fica das linhas no resultado, como eu faria?

Comment: Já está em cima @Adrianoguedes, com `.split()`

Comment: ok muito obrigado amigo!

Comment: @Miguel para remover o `\n`, o correto é o `.strip()` e não `.split()`. No seu código está ok, acho que foi só no comentário que digitou `.split()` ao invés de `.strip()`.

Comment: @Adrianoguedes se a resposta do colega respondeu a sua pergunta, você pode [aceitá-la como resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).